# IPtables string match for some URLs

Tags: linux, networking, centos, iptables, firewall

I'm trying to write iptables *string match* rule to block `http://example.com:8888` and `https://example.com:8888` when it matches the supplied string in the rule. And another rule to redirect the ports also from 8888 to 7777.

I tried following rules but unfortunately didn't work:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 -m string --string linuxcore --algo bm --sport 8888 -j DROP
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m string --algo bm --string linuxcore -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8888 -j DROP
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8888 -m string --algo bm --string "linuxcore" -j REDIRECT --to-port 7777
iptables  -A INPUT -t nat -p tcp --dport 8888 -m string --algo bm --string "linuxcore" -j DROP
```

Comment: You can't do a string block on https, its encrypted.

Comment: @Patrick What about the rule used for http .?

Comment: @linuxcore, you are trying to drive a nail with a screwdriver.  Do not block URLs with `iptables`... block URLs with a proxy like `privoxy` or `squid`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to do something significantly more complicated than I think you want.

What you're asking for:

Block a specific string in the payload (layer 7) of a packet. This will prevent someone from sending an email or IM mentioning a string "linuxcore", or from posting comments in forums about it.

What I think you want:

Redirect packets destined for any IP address resolved by the name domain.com and destined for port 8888 to port 7777.

I'll assume what I think you want, since the former doesn't make very much sense. I am also assuming that you're not interested in matching "foo.domain.com". Remember that it's **ip** tables, not **dns** tables.

In this case, lines 1, 2 and 4 are unnecessary. And you don't want string matching. `iptables` is smart enough to turn names into the appropriate IP addresses and multiplex the rules as necessary. Furthermore, since you're using `PREROUTING`, know that this will only match *coming into your system*, not packets *leaving* your system (if you want to match packets leaving you need to use `OUTPUT`, or alternatively have one of each).

That rule would look like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d domain.com -p tcp --dport 8888 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 7777
```